# Publish Android Library to jCenter

Tags: android, android-library, publishing, bintray, jcenter

I'm attempting to learn how to publish an Android library.

I've followed the instructions from this blog:

http://florentchampigny.com/publish-a-library-to-jcenter

But when I get to the last step and press the "Add to jCenter" button I get the following error:

> Please fix the following before submitting a jCenter inclusion
>   request: - Add a POM file to the latest version of your package.

I see file listed named "Industry-0.0.0-alpha0.pom?override=1", but when I click on it I get the message:

The requested path was not found.

If it helps:

My repository is located at: https://bintray.com/labermt/Industry

My source code is located at: https://github.com/labermt/IndustrySampler

I'm totally new to this, so it could easily be something simple. I'm also looking for blogs or documentation to help me understand how to do this. This blog has gotten me the closest so far.

Thx.

Answer (score 4):

All of your files contain the `?override=1` in the file path.
Bintray doesn't recognize the .pom and .jar files due to this.
You will need to re-deploy your maven files, this time without the `?override=1` in the **file path**.

[image: see Image]

Comment: How do I do that? The only place I see anything close to this in the blog is: bintray {
    ...
    override = true
    ...

Comment: I saw a bug somewhere that said if you set override=true, then you get a 404 error. I'm going to set it to false and upgrade to classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3' to see what happens.

Comment: Now I only get 404 errors... Even if I put everything back as was... Very confusing. I'm going to reboot my computer. Could this be a problem with bintray bugs?

Comment: It's a bintray bug. Upgrading to 1.7.3 fixed it.